# Performance SQL - JSON extraction

Tags: sql-server

I need to extract an ID from some a string field (JSON code).
From performance perspective what is the best way to obtain this ID and where?

Remarks:

- there are different type of messages
- payload: JSON field
- sample of message type1: {"RequestId":"4B5E95D49D3E46548904083D0CD17521"}
- sample of message type2:{"createdById":"XXXXXXXXX","requestId":"15F79EC78E5243A487337C0FE61A9E00","sessionId":null}
- SQL in order to extract the id:

```
select  
    (Case 
        when eventType = 'Type1' then substring (payload, CHARINDEX('{',payload)+ LEN('{"RequestId":"'),   CHARINDEX ('"}', payload) -( CHARINDEX('{',payload)+ LEN('{"RequestId":"'))) 
        when eventType = ' Type2' then substring (payload, CHARINDEX('"requestId":"',payload)+ LEN('"requestId":"'),   CHARINDEX ('","sessionId"', payload) -(  CHARINDEX('"requestId":"',payload)+ LEN('"requestId":"'))) 
        else 'none' END) as RequestID 
  from table
```

Comment: Why use `CHARINDEX` and `SUBSTRING` not use SQL Server's JSON functionality?

Comment: And your `@@version` of SQL Server is... - ?

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio 15.0.18384.0 (Azure)

Comment: Thanks! Larnu...to tell you the truth , it is really the first time that I'm working in something like this, I'm truly not familiar with these capabilities

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running SQL Server 2016+ then use this query:

```
select JSON_VALUE(t.payload, '$.requestId') from table t
```